# Loading Integer Array from xml

Tags: android

I have an integer array in an xml file as follows

```
<integer-array name="myArray">
    <item>@drawable/pic1</item>
    <item>@drawable/pic2</item>
    <item>@drawable/pic3</item>
    <item>@drawable/pic4</item>
</integer-array>
```

In the code, I am trying to load this array

```
int[] picArray = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.myArray);
```

The expected result is

```
R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2,R.drawable.pic3
```

but instead it is coming with an array with all values as zero

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: have you tried to put just integers?!

Comment: My Xml as follows. 

The java code getResources().getIntArray(R.array.myArray) gives incorrect result whereas 
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myWord) is giving correct result


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="myword">
        <item>Word1</item>
        <item>word2</item>
    </string-array>
    <integer-array name="myArray">
 <item>@drawable/pic1</item>
 <item>@drawable/pic2</item>
 <item>@drawable/pic3</item>
    </integer-array>
</resources>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get an array with id's of your images.
Probably [this article](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2009/12/dynamically-retrieving-resources-in.html) helps you. And so the code you probably need:

```
int[] picArray = new int[4];

for (int i = 1; i <=4; i++)
{
  try 
  {
    Class res = R.drawable.class;
    Field field = res.getField("pic"+i);
    picArray[i-1] = field.getInt(null);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Log.e("MyTag", "Failure to get drawable id.", e);
  }
}
```

Comment: I can see reflection classes are used here. Is this the only way? Is there a way I can make getResources.getIntArray work?

Answer (score 12):

Found this [solution](http://www.anddev.org/code-snippets-for-android-f33/xml-integer-array-resource-references-getintarray-t9268.html):

```
TypedArray ar = context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.myArray);
int len = ar.length();

int[] picArray = new int[len];

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    picArray[i] = ar.getResourceId(i, 0);

ar.recycle();

// Do stuff with resolved reference array, resIds[]...
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    Log.v (TAG, "Res Id " + i + " is " + Integer.toHexString(picArray[i]));
```

And resources xml file could be:

```
<resources>
    <integer-array name="myArray">
        <item>@drawable/pic1</item>
        <item>@drawable/pic2</item>
        <item>@drawable/pic3</item>
        <item>@drawable/pic4</item>
    </integer-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Great.. Thanks..!!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you might be talking about typed arrays?

if so a typed array should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="icons">
        <item>@drawable/home</item>
        <item>@drawable/settings</item>
        <item>@drawable/logout</item>
    </array>
    <array name="colors">
        <item>#FFFF0000</item>
        <item>#FF00FF00</item>
        <item>#FF0000FF</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Can you show us your actual xml file so we can help you?

EDIT: Yeah those are not integers. make it a resource array if you want to store resources.

Comment: My Xml as follows. 

The java code getResources().getIntArray(R.array.myArray) gives incorrect result whereas 
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myWord) is giving correct result


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="myword">
        <item>Word1</item>
        <item>word2</item>
    </string-array>
    <integer-array name="myArray">
 <item>@drawable/pic1</item>
 <item>@drawable/pic2</item>
 <item>@drawable/pic3</item>
    </integer-array>
</resources>

Comment: I'm still unclear as to what you're doing, your second example will give correct results because you're getting a string array which is what it expects, but your integer array in xml doesn't have integers in it it has resource paths. I think you should check out Mur Votema's answer. seems to be what you might be trying to do.

Comment: I have the list under resources.xml. Tried using array instead of Integer-array. How do I load this array object? I used getResources().getIntArray(R.array.newarrayname) and still getting same result (i.e. and array of zeros). I thought @drawable/home will be stored as int!

Comment: no its not stored as int. i can see how you would make that conclusion because in android code they are ints but only after being converted by java. when you make an int-array it has to contain ints, as in: 1, 2, 3. integer primitives. don't use getIntArray because they are not ints. you could use getstringarray if you want to store the paths in a string, but as I said I'm still unclear what you're doing and Mur Votema's link to the tutorial seems to be the type of thing you want to do.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand. I think I should follow Mur Votema's code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Just make it a normal resource array. You could do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <array name="icons">
       <item>@drawable/home</item>
       <item>@drawable/settings</item>
       <item>@drawable/logout</item>
   </array>
</resources>
```

Then don't make a int[] just make a TypedArray like this:

```
TypedArray icons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);
```

and get it with:

```
imageview.setImageDrawable(mIcons.getDrawable(position));
```

Comment: Don't forget to `icons.recycle()` when done.