# Get Layouts using integer-array Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I would like to retrieve the layouts' address using a  from my java file. However, what I get is 0.

res/values/worlds.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer-array
        name="world1">
        <item>@layout/lvl_1</item>
        <item>@layout/lvl_1</item>
    </integer-array>
</resources>
```

and the Java code which I use to get the array:

```
Resources res = getResources();
int[] layouts = res.getIntArray(R.array.world1);
setContentView(layouts[0]);
```

the Java code gives me a 0 on my Logcat though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading Interger Array from xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444950/loading-interger-array-from-xml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<item>@layout/lvl_1</item>
```

is not type of Integer. so use array in xml to store items and `obtainTypedArray` in code for getting Array of items from xml  then use `getResourceId` to pass layout id to `setContentView` as :

res/values/worlds.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array
        name="world1">
        <item>@layout/lvl_1</item>
        <item>@layout/lvl_1</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

In code set layout as:

```
TypedArray layouts = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.world1);
int layoutid=layouts.getResourceId(0, -1);
setContentView(layoutid);
layouts.recycle();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Forgive me but, if I may add, is there any way to store this typed array to a <List>? I would want to use Collections.shuffle on the retrieved layouts' ids