# Incompatible types, required java.lang.Integer[], found Int[]?

Tags: java, android, arrays

So i have an array of Integers "images_array" stored in strings.xml. I am trying to extract it into my Websites.java file to use it to display images.

But i get this error for some reason:

[image]

I tried storing the array in the same file as the one that is calling it, and it works, its just that, calling it from strings.xml is not working for me. maybe there is something i didnt learn yet?

Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444950/loading-integer-array-from-xml

Comment: You should consider asking another question instead of changing the one you've asked before. The link before should answer this one though. And don't use `R.drawable.pic2` in XML

Comment: I am sorry, i am new to SO. I will ask this as a new question. Btw,thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 6):

`Integer` and `int` can be used interchangeably, because the compiler wraps and unwraps these automatically.

This doesn't count for arrays. `Integer[]` and `int[]` are two totally different types. `getIntArray()` returns `int[]`, so you cannot declare `images` as `Integer[]` or have to copy the items manually. But better don't even use `Integer` if not necessary.

```
int[] images;
```

Comment: When i use int the way you suggested, the error is gone but the image wont show on screen.

Answer (score 1):

Change the data type of 'images' from "Integer[]" to "int[]"